# how to exclude files when using globpath() function

Tags: vim, glob

I want to obtain in Vim any file in a path that doesn't have a `.tex` or `.bib` extension.

I tried (in order to ignore tex files) the following command

```
:echo globpath({some path}, '*.[^tex]*')
```

but that will also ignore combinations of `tex` characters (for instance `.toc` files).

So how can I modify the pattern in order to match any file without `.tex` or `.bib` extension?

**Edit:** Vim' negative lookahead is done with `\@!`. I have a directory `/test` with the files `foo.bib`, `foo.tex`, `foo.pdf`, `foo.aux` and `foo.toc`. I tried doing

```
:echo globpath('C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/test', '\w*\.\%\(tex\|bib\)\@!')
```

but that returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use `globpath()` function, you don't need regex. it's a glob function. you can just set the `wig` option (wildignore) , then call the function .

```
set wig=*.bib,*.tex
```

then

```
:echo globpath('/your/path','*.*')
```

do a test:

```
kent$  pwd
/tmp/test

kent$  ls -1
bar.bib
bib.bar
f.txt
tex.foo
x.tex
```

in vim:

```
:set wig=*.bib,*.tex
:echo globpath('/tmp/test','*')
```

we got:

```
/tmp/test/bib.bar
/tmp/test/f.txt
/tmp/test/tex.foo
```

note that you can call it `globpath('/path','*',0,1)` to have returned value in a `list`, sometimes it is handy to use in script.